# Java Spring WebFlux WebClient pass parameters to response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I want to use webflux to return a single result async. The response doesn't have an id of the object. So when I get the response async back from the remote reply, then I don't have a way to fetch that object from the database to get further information. So is there a way to pass my object id to the async response handler? I couldn't find any way. Here is my sample code

```
var monoReply = webClient.post().uri(url)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .body(Mono.just(myRequestObject), MyRequest.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(MyResponse.class);
    monoReply.subscribe(BanlawApiServiceImpl::handleLoginResponse);

private static String handleLoginResponse(MyResponse myResponse) {
    String token = myResponse.getToken();
    //now I want to know the id of the database object I am dealing with. Response doesn't 
    have that id
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to continue async flow using `flatMap` and  fetch object from the database. As result `handleLoginResponse` should return `Mono<T>`

```
webClient.post().uri(url)
       .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
       .body(Mono.just(myRequestObject), MyRequest.class)
       .retrieve()
       .bodyToMono(MyResponse.class)
       .flatMap(response -> handleLoginResponse(response))


private static Mono<String> handleLoginResponse(MyResponse myResponse) {
    ...
}
```

Not sure why you are subscribing to the flow explicitly that usually is anti-pattern and should be avoided. In WebFlux subscription happens behind the scene.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. How do you fetch the database object after you get the async response from the remote server? How do you pass the db id (primary key)? You don't have that key in the response itself.

Comment: Also your code is not compiling. Try to update the code

Comment: I would suggest to read more about reactive programming. This snippet shows how to continue reactive flow and use response in your handler. It's not really clear where is your db id coming from, but you could simply pass it to the `handleLoginResponse` function. If you need more help, try to update the original question with more details.